# Which packages are needed for a full kubuntu desktop?

Tags: upgrade, xubuntu, kubuntu, 13.10

I changed from Xubuntu 13.10 to Kubuntu by installing the package `kubuntu-desktop` with its dependencies by

```
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
```

But the system seems to lack some features, I think.

So are there any packages that are usually installed from a fresh Kubuntu-CD that are missing when you just swap from Xubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Try installing with `sudo apt-get install kubuntu-full`, it should get you the complete netbook/desktop Plasma edition. You can then go through the list of [available Kubuntu packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=kubuntu&searchon=names&suite=saucy&section=all).